# Text Classification + NLP + Data-mining + Data Science: Should I do stop word removal and stemming before applying tf-idf?

Tags: nlp, data-mining, data-science, text-classification, tf-idf

I am working on a text classification problem. The problem is explained below:

I have a dataset of events which contains three columns - name of the event, description of the event, category of the event. There are about 32 categories in the dataset, such as, travel, sport, education, business etc. I have to classify each event to a category depending on its name and description.

What I understood is this particular task of classification is highly dependent on keywords, rather than, semantics. I am giving you two examples:

If the word 'football' is found either in the name or description or in both, it is highly likely that the event is about sport.

If the word 'trekking' is found either in the name or description or in both, it is highly likely that the event is about travel.

We are not considering multiple categories for an event(however, that's a plan for future !! )

I hope applying tf-idf before Multinomial Naive Bayes would lead to decent result for this problem. My question is:

Should I do stop word removal and stemming before applying tf-idf or should I apply tf-idf just on raw text? Here text means entries in name of event and description columns.

Answer (score 2):

The question is too generic and you are not providing samples of the dataset, code, and not even indicating the language you are using. To this regard, I will presume that you are using English, since the two words that you are providing as an example are "football" and "trekking". The answer will however necessarily be generic.

> Should I do stop word removal

**Yes**. Have a look at [this](http://letterfrequency.org/word-frequency-english-language/) to see the most frequent words in the English language. As you can see they have no semantic meaning, and thus would not contribute to solving the classification task that you have proposed. if `stopwords` is a list containing stopwords, the parameter `stop_words=stopwords` passed to the `CountVectorizer` or `TfidfVectorizer` constructor will automatically exclude the stopwords when invoking the `.fit_transform()` method.

> Should I do stemming

**It depends**. Languages other than English, whose grammar rules allow for a big number of possible prefixes-suffixes, normally require stemming when performing classification task, in order to reach any useful result. The English language however has very poor grammar rules, and thus you can often get away without stemming/lemmatization. You should check the results obtained against the desired accuracy first, and if it is insufficient, try adding a stemming/lemmatization step in the preprocessing of your data. Stemming is a computationally expensive process for large corpora, and I personally use it only for languages that require it.

> I hope applying tf-idf before Multinomial Naive Bayes would lead to decent result for this problem

**Careful with this**. While tf-idf in practice works with Naive Bayesian classifiers, this is not the way that specific classifier is meant to be used. From the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html),
`The multinomial distribution normally requires integer feature counts. However, in practice, fractional counts such as tf-idf may also work.` It is in your best interest to tackle the classification task with `CountVectorizer` first and score it, and after you have a baseline accuracy for evaluating the `TfidfVectorizer`, check whether its results are better or worse than those of the CountVectorizer.

If you post some code and a sample of your dataset we can help you with that, otherwise this should be enough.